# pound sign in javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I wanna constrain to input special signs like £ ¬ ¦ in javascript,but they are always displayed in  ��� on Page source. How can i let them display correctly and page can be validated ? my page is using utf-8

thanks

Comment: which server side language are you using?

Comment: and what is your document type?

Comment: my doucyment type is : <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

Comment: server side language  is classic asp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure that:

- You really are using UTF-8 for the page
- You are using UTF-8 for the JS
- Your HTTP headers say you are using UTF-8
- Any `<meta>` tags you have which mention an encoding say UTF-8

If you can't confirm all of those, you can use: `"\u00A3"`

Comment: i have already using <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
but how can i know i am using UTF-8 for the JS

Comment: You seem to be confusing step 1 and step 4. For steps 1 and 2, assuming that nothing munges the data on the way, look at the configuration of your editor.

Comment: sorry i don't understand. It seems that i just put UTF-8 on the HTTP headers. I should confirm  "You really are using UTF-8 for the page
# You are using UTF-8 for the JS". javascript codes are outside the form

Comment: i put like these <script type="text/javascript" src="[path]/myscript.js" charset="utf-8"></script>, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Jason: look at the current text encoding to see what your browser is using. In Firefox, you can look at [menu bar] View > Character Encoding and see in the sub-menu which one is selected.